# Disable LFH in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, heap-memory, windbg

I'm looking to disable the LFH for an application I'm trying to debug.  I'm able to rebuild and redeploy the application, but I cannot attach a debugger or set any gflags.

What's a good way to disable the LFH with these constraints?  Is there maybe an attribute I can modify on the executable itself?  Or some startup code I can add to the program?

Comment: Low Force Helix? Lake Forest Hospital? Low Fragment Heap? Can you specify what you are looking for?

Comment: @Bo: You're being ridiculous.  This acronym means only one thing on Windows, and he did clearly say Windows in both the title and the tags.  And `heap` in the tags.  And mentioned `gflags`.

Comment: @Ben - I sure didn't get it, and it is not on the first page of Google. Is it still *obvious*?

Comment: @Bo: Not on the first page?  When I use the keywords from this question's title, [the first 9 hits](https://www.google.com/#q=windows+lfh) are relevant.

Comment: @Ben - It might depend on where you are located. I get google.se by default, where heap stuff appears in middle of page 2 http://www.google.se/search?q=lfh (just before Li Fook Hing school in Hong Kong)

Comment: @Bo: When I try [google.se](https://www.google.se/#q=windows+lfh), only the first four results are useful.

Comment: So the new definition of "obvious" is that a keyword search in Google nets you relevant hits?  :)

Comment: Even if it's obvious, I see nothing wrong with spelling out acronyms the first time they're used. If only to *eliminate* the possibility of ambiguity and enhance searchability.

Comment: What is the target operating system?

Comment: The title reads "Diable LFH in Windows".  So maybe Linux.

Answer (score 2):

On Vista and Win7, I think you can disable the Low-Fragmentation Heap on a per-executable basis with the Application Compatibility Toolkit.

On XP, [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366750.aspx) suggests [you don't get a LFH by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366705.aspx).  So probably it is your C++ runtime library (which you haven't named) that is turning it on.  And it cannot be disabled once enabled.  So check the documentation for your particular runtime library to see if you can tell it not to enable LFH, or if there's another version of the runtime library you can link with that doesn't enable it.

See also [this thread on the Microsoft forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vcgeneral/thread/8123ce6d-f291-4efa-8a07-977d0bda0347)

Comment: Starting with Vista, LFH is enabled by default.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366750(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Brain2000: That's what my answer already said.  And I already provided that link.

Comment: You're right.  My comment makes no sense for the current answer's text.  Though I see the answer was edited after I left my comment.  Perhaps it said "enabled" instead of "disabled", which would have made my comment valid at the time it was posted.  If not, then accept my apologies, I read it backwards.

Comment: @Brain2000: You can see the edit history by clicking where it said edited.  The edit added the last line (the link to the MS forums).  Nothing inherently wrong with a redundant comment, I just wanted to make sure you hadn't found something actually wrong with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can use the `gflags.exe` tool that's included with the WDK (maybe also the SDK via the Debugging Tools for Windows package) to manipulate a subset of the gflags in the executable image's PE header.  Just go to the "Image File" tab in 'gflags.exe'.</strike>

As pointed out by jcopenha in a comment, it looks like gflags.exe does not manipulate the PE file header (I was relying on information from "Windows Internals, Fifth Edition" in Chapter 9's "Heap Debugging Features" section) - apparently it only manipulates the "Image File Execution Options" registry key.

However, it may still be possible possible to set (or clear) the gflags bits for a particular executable in the image - see [the docs for the `IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680328.aspx); in particular the `GlobalFlagsClear` and `GlobalFlagsSet` fields:

- GlobalFlagsClear - The global flags that control system behavior. For more information, see Gflags.exe.
- GlobalFlagsSet - The global flags that control system behavior. For more information, see Gflags.exe.

You can dump these fields with `dumpbin` (or `link /dump`) using the `/loadconfig` option:

```
C:\temp>dumpbin /loadconfig test.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file test.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  Section contains the following load config:

            00000048 size
                   0 time date stamp
                0.00 Version
                   0 GlobalFlags Clear
                   0 GlobalFlags Set             // <=======
                   0 Critical Section Default Timeout

 // remainder of dump snipped...
```

You can get the `RVA` of the "Load Configuration Directory" using `dumpbin /headers`:

```
C:\temp>dumpbin /headers test.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file test.exe

// ...

OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES

// ...

           142B0 [      40] RVA [size] of Load Configuration Directory
//         ^^^^^            ^^^
// ...
```

As a point of interest, the `/loadconfig` and `/headers` option disagree on the size of the structure (for the record, it looks like the `/header` info isn't right)

Unfortunately, I'm unaware of PE editor that directly supports these fields - you'll probably have to use a hex editor (or the hex editing feature of a PE editor) to change those fields.  The RVA of the `IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY` structure should help you find it in the hex editor.

I believe that setting one or more of the heap debugging flags in the image header (maybe any of them, but you might have to experiment) will disable the low fragmentation heap. But I haven't tested whether or not setting bits in these fields actually works. If you try this, please let us know how it fares.

Comment: Based on the mention in the question, I think he already knows about `gflags`.

Comment: I thought that perhaps he wasn't aware that `gflags.exe` could be used to affect only the executable instead of affecting the machine's global configuration. My impression on the constraints was that access to the machine and it's configuration was limited to deploying a new build. Using `gflags.exe` to set PE header bits is more or less equivalent to 'rebuilding and redeploying' the application - no configuration of the machine needs to take place. As also mentioned in the question: "Is there maybe an attribute I can modify on the executable itself?"

Comment: gflags.exe doesn't change the PE header it sets information in the registry for that image. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @jcopenha: looks like you're right. I got some bad info (and made the mistake of not verifying). I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Michael Burr's comment above about the IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY containing GlobalFlagSet I wrote the following code to demonstrate enabling the correct GlobalFlag to disable the Low Fragmentation Heap.  One caveat about writing your own IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY at compile time is that it disables SafeSEH.

```
// editloadconfig.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>


/*
typedef struct {
    DWORD   Size;
    DWORD   TimeDateStamp;
    WORD    MajorVersion;
    WORD    MinorVersion;
    DWORD   GlobalFlagsClear;
    DWORD   GlobalFlagsSet;
    DWORD   CriticalSectionDefaultTimeout;
    DWORD   DeCommitFreeBlockThreshold;
    DWORD   DeCommitTotalFreeThreshold;
    DWORD   LockPrefixTable;            // VA
    DWORD   MaximumAllocationSize;
    DWORD   VirtualMemoryThreshold;
    DWORD   ProcessHeapFlags;
    DWORD   ProcessAffinityMask;
    WORD    CSDVersion;
    WORD    Reserved1;
    DWORD   EditList;                   // VA
    DWORD   SecurityCookie;             // VA
    DWORD   SEHandlerTable;             // VA
    DWORD   SEHandlerCount;
} IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY32, *PIMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY32;
*/


extern "C" 
IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY _load_config_used = { 0x48, 0, 0, 0,0, 0x00000020/*enable heap free checking*/};
// change the last value to 0 to not enable any globalflags


#define HEAP_STANDARD 0
#define HEAP_LAL 1
#define HEAP_LFH 2
#define SIZE 100

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   BOOL bResult;
   HANDLE hHeap;
   ULONG HeapInformation;
   void* allocb[0x12+1];


   // based on "Understanding the LFH" paper at
   // http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CE0QFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fillmatics.com%2FUnderstanding_the_LFH.pdf&ei=GlBvT9yrMKHy0gGHpLnaBg&usg=AFQjCNGsvVtl54X7MWGyWYqiSrsdTBrbXQ
   int i = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < 0x12; i++) 
   { 
        printf("Allocation 0x%02x for 0x%02x bytes\n", i, SIZE); 
        allocb[i] = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0x0, SIZE); 
   }

   printf("Allocation 0x%02x for 0x%02x bytes\n", i++, SIZE); 
   printf("\tFirst serviced by the LFH\n"); 
   allocb[i] = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0x0, SIZE);
   // LFH is now activated so the query below will return 0 or 2.

   // sample code from MSDN for querying heap information
   //
   // Get a handle to the default process heap.
   //
   hHeap = GetProcessHeap();
   if (hHeap == NULL) {
       _tprintf(TEXT("Failed to retrieve default process heap with LastError %d.\n"),
                GetLastError());
       return 1;
   }

   //
   // Query heap features that are enabled.
   //
   bResult = HeapQueryInformation(hHeap,
                                  HeapCompatibilityInformation,
                                  &HeapInformation,
                                  sizeof(HeapInformation),
                                  NULL);
   if (bResult == FALSE) {
       _tprintf(TEXT("Failed to retrieve heap features with LastError %d.\n"),
                GetLastError());
       return 1;
   }

   //
   // Print results of the query.
   //
   _tprintf(TEXT("HeapCompatibilityInformation is %d.\n"), HeapInformation);
   switch(HeapInformation)
   {
   case HEAP_STANDARD:
       _tprintf(TEXT("The default process heap is a standard heap.\n"));
       break;
   case HEAP_LAL:
       _tprintf(TEXT("The default process heap supports look-aside lists.\n"));
       break;
   case HEAP_LFH:
       _tprintf(TEXT("The default process heap has the low-fragmentation ") \
                TEXT("heap enabled.\n"));
       break;
   default:
       _tprintf(TEXT("Unrecognized HeapInformation reported for the default ") \
                TEXT("process heap.\n"));
       break;
    }

   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Nice - I thought dealing with this would require manual editing with a hex editor (or writing some program/script to do the editing). How did you find out to use `_load_config_used` to set up this structure in the PE image? I found only two references on MSDN: one was completely unrelated  and the second was related but discussed only "safeseh" and used `_load_config_used` without really talking about what the purpose was (referring to the loadcfg.c CRT source for details).

Comment: Oops, didn't source all of my material. This article, http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicsarticles/anin-depthlookintothewin32portableexecutablefileformat-part1 , lead me to the _load_config_used portion.  Lucky google hit.

Comment: Looking at `vc/crt/src/intel/loadcfg.c`, it's pretty easy to get the safeSEH support back by adding a few externs and dropping their addresses into the correct slots at the end of the `_load_config_used` struct.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way if you can't change the configuration on the machine, is to set the heap information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366705(v=vs.85).aspx

I believe you can disable the LFH heap programmatically this way, although I haven't tried it.

Comment: The problem is that you can't do this for the process default heap - it's set up before you get a chance at it.